# What are the equivalent ganache json rpc methods for the hardhat local node?

Tags: hardhat, ganache

The ganache local node implements a few debugging/test methods that the [hardhat local node](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#special-testing/debugging-methods) does not such as the following:

- `evm_mineBlockNumber`, params: [blockNumber]
- `evm_setTime`, params: [unixSeconds]
- `evm_freezeTime`, params: [seconds]
- `miner_start`
- `miner_stop`

How can the behaviour of these methods be replicated in hardhat?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this hardhat doc to find some of the corresponding methods and their helpers here:

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference

Comment: Thanks for this, though I couldn't find any equivalents to evm_freezeTime, miner_start and miner_stop. 

evm_setTime can be emulated using increaseTo(newTimestamp), evm_mineBlockNumber can be using mineUpTo(blockNumber);